# Not able to access parent fields

Tags: php

I'm learning some PHP right now, and as an exercise I'm writing a pair of very simple database connector classes, with echo statements:

```
<?php

class DBConnector {
    protected $hostname;
    protected $username;
    protected $db_name;
    protected $pass;
    protected $conn;

    function __construct($host, $user, $pwd, $db) {
        echo phpversion() . "<br>";
        $hostname = $host;
        $username = $user;
        $pass = $pwd;
        $db_name = $db;
        echo "parent constructor hostname: " . $hostname . "<br>";
        echo "parent constructor username: " . $username . "<br>";
        echo "parent constructor pass: " . $pass . "<br>";
        echo "parent constructor db_name: " . $db_name . "<br>";
    }
}

class MYSQLConnector extends DBConnector {

    function __construct($host, $user, $pwd, $db) {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
        echo "child constructor hostname: " . $host . "<br>";
        echo "child constructor username: " . $user . "<br>";
        echo "child constructor pass: " . $pwd . "<br>";
        echo "child constructor db_name: " . $db . "<br>";
        echo "child accessing parent's hostname: " . $this->hostname . "<br>";
        echo "child accessing parent's username: " . $this->username . "<br>";
        echo "child accessing parent's pass: " . $this->pass . "<br>";
        echo "child accessing parent's db_name: " . $this->db_name . "<br>";
    }

    // Open connection to database
    function open_connection() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->pass, $this->db_name);
        if($conn->connect_errorno) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Send query to database
    function submit_query($query) {
        // nothing bad could ever happen with this
        return $conn->query($query);
    }
}

?>
```

However, the result of the echo statements is as follows:

```
5.5.38
parent constructor hostname: localhost
parent constructor username: web_connection
parent constructor pass: 1234
parent constructor db_name: test
child constructor hostname: localhost
child constructor username: web_connection
child constructor pass: 1234
child constructor db_name: test
child accessing parent's hostname: (nothing printed)
child accessing parent's username: (nothing printed)
child accessing parent's pass: (nothing printed)
child accessing parent's db_name: (nothing printed)
```

The parent fields are clearly being set when the constructor is called, so that isn't the issue. However, trying to access the parent class's members with `$this->` in the child class doesn't seem to access the variable as I expect, and results in no output. Calling `open_connection()` results in a warning due to blank values being passed into `new mysqli()`:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/classes/database_connectors/mysql_connector.php on line 39
```

All of the documentation I've looked at indicates my code should be correct, and having the fields set as `protected` shouldn't cause any issue. Setting them to `public` doesn't change the result. I guess I could just write some getter methods for those fields, but I shouldn't have to in this situation, if my understanding is correct - so what am I doing wrong here?

This is on a Mac OSX (10.11.6) apache server on my local machine, PHP version 5.5.38.

Comment: In the parent constructor you need `$this->hostname = $host;` etc...

Comment: *"The parent fields are clearly being set when the constructor is called"* -- no, they are not. `$hostname = $host;` -- this statement creates a local variable named `$hostname` that is initialized with the value of variable `$host`. In order to set the class member `$hostname` you must use `$this->hostname = $host;`

Comment: Ah, I see. The way I wrote it would have been correct in java which is where I'm coming from. I guess this is an idiosyncrasy of PHP that went over my head.

Comment: @axiac I'd accept that as an answer if you post it.